# Apache mod_rewrite for SSL Version

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the requirement to redirect all requests that are not encrypted via TLSv1.2 for /login-handler.php to /login-handler-old-tls.php.  I've added the following two lines to my .htaccess file at the root of the site, however when I attempt to load login-handler.php with a TLSv1 browser, it doesn't redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{SSL_PROTOCOL} !^TLSv1\.2$
RewriteRule ^login-handler\.php$ login-handler-old-tls.php [R]
```

I have other Rewrite rules in the .htaccess that work OK, not sure if there's something with my syntax?  I ran phpinfo() from my root directory and confirmed that SSL_PROTOCOL is populated with TLSv1.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, in more research I had some rewrite rules above this one in my .htaccess file that was causing the issue.  The rewrite rules worked once I moved it to the top of the file.  Thanks.